# Why do I need to define the event handler `handleStatusChange` in `useEffect`?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, react-hooks

Can I use `handleStatusChange` event handler outside of the `useEffect` block, and directly in the `FriendStatus` component?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function FriendStatus(props) {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }

    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });

  if (isOnline === null) {
    return 'Loading...';
  }

  return isOnline ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `handleStatusChange` is used with the `ChatAPI`, an external service that is not managed by react (unlike `onClick` for example).

You need to subscribe/unsubscribe a handler to the `ChatAPI` service whenever a `friend.id` changes.

Using the `ChatAPI` directly in the component's body would cause subscribe and unsubscribe to be called on each render. However, the event handler would never unsubscribe because you won't have a reference to the registered function.

The `useEffect` hook solves this problems:

- We can configure the hook's dependency to only call the hook when the `friend.id` changes (see updated code).
- The unsubscribe function always has a reference to the subscribed function, because it's defined in the same closure.

Updated code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function FriendStatus({ friend }) {
  const { id } = friend;
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }

    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(id, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(id, handleStatusChange);
    };
  }, [id]); // id is now used as a dependency 

  if (isOnline === null) {
    return 'Loading...';
  }

  return isOnline ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
}
```